# ErrorDocument 404 to External URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

We have moved our website to new domain name, for SEO purpose we are required to redirect all 404 to new domain name.

```
Our website domain : example.com
Moved to: new-domain.com/example
```

Any non-existent url for domain such as `example.com/non-existent` to `new-domain.com/example/non-existent`

I tried with following in my .htaccess file and It does not work.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://new-domain.com/example/%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This is a WordPress installation, apart from handing this with WordPress hook, is there a htaccess solution?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache version 2.4.18

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix error document with server variables like that. You can try using a mod-rewrite. Put this rule above your current wordpress rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new-example.com/example%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is this in any way conflict with the existing redirects we got using the WordPress plugin?

Comment: I don't know what plugins you have. But that is why I said you have to put this first above WP rules, so it will execute these rules and then process WP rules. It shouldn't affect your current rules on your new site, which is why I put the first condition.

Comment: I found one issue, can you check my question with updated section.

Comment: Those redirects are before the rewrite rules, I don't see how they can be affecting the 2 you said aren't working.

Comment: BTW I don't like mixing rewrite and mod-alias together as sometimes weird stuff pops up. Why not convert those redirects to rewrite rules? e.g. `RewriteRule ^cookie-policy/? http://www.digite.com/ [R=301,L]`